# Navigating through a 3D array Java in a different order

Tags: java, arrays

It's been a while since I have used java and I am currently trying to iterate over a 3d array.

This array is structured as Object[][][] dataSet, where Object[company][event][number]. Now I want to iterate over it in such a manner that I can iterate through every number, after I iterate through all these numbers I want to increase the company index, so I can check the other companies. When I reach the end of the companies I want to increase the event index and try all over again.

Sort of like:
Iterate through each number of company "m"
when company "m" is searched through, go to the next company
if all company m are searched: increase event and restart the search.

The reason for doing it in this manner is, I want to create a list at the end that contains all numbers from all companies for each event like so: T1 is all numbers for event 1, T2 all numbers for event 2, etc.

I did a 3 nested for loop, and I am modifying it, but I am a bit confused over what to do exactly and would like some guidance about the idea.

Edit 1:
As of now, my current try follows this format and idea:

```
for(int i=0; i<dataSet.length; i++) {//company
                for(int j=0; j<dataSet[i].length; j++) {//event
                    for(int k=0; k<dataSet[i][j].length; k++) {//numbers
                        System.out.print(dataSet[i][j][k]);
                        System.out.println(" positions: "+ i + " " + j + " ");
                    }   
                }
            }
```

Currently, I am trying to sort of swap the for loops trying to make the first for loop into a loop that iterates through events using an external variable. and the second loop would iterate through companies.
Making this:

```
for(int i=0; i<dataSet[company].length; i++) {//event
            if (company < dataSet.length-1) {
                company++;
            }
            for(int j=0; j<dataSet.length; j++) {//company
                for(int k=0; k<dataSet[j][i].length; k++) {//numbers
                    System.out.print(dataSet[j][i][k]);
                    System.out.println(" positions: "+ j + " " + i + " ");
                }   
            }
        }
```

The result this is currently giving is essentially the same as having a normal 3 nested loop

A bit more info:

```
Set[0][0] = 9  
Set[0][1] = 0  1  3  4  6  7  8  9  
Set[0][2] = 9  
Set[0][3] = 9  
Set[0][4] = 0  1  2  4  5  6  7  8  9  
Set[0][5] = 0  1  2  3  4  5  7  8  9  
Set[0][6] = 0  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  
Set[0][7] = 0  1  2  3  4  6  7  8  9  
Set[0][8] = 9  
Set[0][9] = 9  
Set[1][0] = 
Set[1][1] = 
Set[1][2] = 
Set[1][3] = 
Set[1][4] = 
Set[1][5] = 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  
Set[1][6] = 
Set[1][7] = 
Set[1][8] = 
Set[1][9] =
```

these are my sets that are my 3d array

```
9 positions: 0 0 
0 positions: 0 1 
1 positions: 0 1 
3 positions: 0 1 
4 positions: 0 1 
6 positions: 0 1 
7 positions: 0 1 
8 positions: 0 1 
9 positions: 0 1 
9 positions: 0 2 
9 positions: 0 3 
0 positions: 0 4 
1 positions: 0 4 
2 positions: 0 4 
4 positions: 0 4 
5 positions: 0 4 
6 positions: 0 4 
7 positions: 0 4 
8 positions: 0 4 
9 positions: 0 4 
0 positions: 0 5 
1 positions: 0 5 
2 positions: 0 5 
3 positions: 0 5 
4 positions: 0 5 
5 positions: 0 5 
7 positions: 0 5 
8 positions: 0 5 
9 positions: 0 5 
2 positions: 1 5 
3 positions: 1 5 
4 positions: 1 5 
5 positions: 1 5 
6 positions: 1 5 
7 positions: 1 5 
8 positions: 1 5
```

these are my iterations, skipping any that is empty

The correct output should have something along these lines:

```
9 positions: 0 0 
empty positions: 1 0
0 positions: 0 1 
empty positions: 1 1 
...
0 positions: 0 5 
1 positions: 0 5 
2 positions: 0 5 
3 positions: 0 5 
4 positions: 0 5 
5 positions: 0 5 
7 positions: 0 5 
8 positions: 0 5 
9 positions: 0 5 
2 positions: 1 5 
3 positions: 1 5 
4 positions: 1 5 
5 positions: 1 5 
6 positions: 1 5 
7 positions: 1 5 
8 positions: 1 5
```

Hope that gives a bit more insight.

Edit 2: New idea: It is a given information that I can always know how many events and companies there will be in this case: 2 companies and 10 events, so I will try to make a for loop with this in mind and will update with my results.

Comment: Please share your tries and explain how it does NOT solve your problem

Comment: added a bit more information about what I have done, and my data sets. Hope its a bit more insightful now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that over my complication and confusion I failed to properly look and assess:

```
    int event = 10;
    int company = 2;
    
    //for(int pos=0; pos < event-1; pos++) {
        
        for(int i=0; i<event; i++) {//event
    
            for(int j=0; j<company; j++) {//company
                                    
                for(int k=0; k<dataSet[j][i].length; k++) {//numbers
                    
                    System.out.print(dataSet[j][i][k]);
                    System.out.println(" positions: "+ j + " " + i + " ");
                            
                }
            }
        }
```

The idea I initially had does work, and I leave it here for future reference and for others if they ever come into the same issue.

The issue in my results was failing to analyze my datasets, it gave the appearance of giving me the wrong result, but that is because I did not take into account the empty sets, when I was doing it manually. When I changed the sets in order to have no empty sets you could see that the code functioned correctly like so:

```
Set[0][0] = 9  
Set[0][1] = 0  1  3  4  6  7  8  9  
Set[0][2] = 9  
Set[0][3] = 9  
Set[0][4] = 0  1  2  4  5  6  7  8  9  
Set[0][5] = 0  1  2  3  4  5  7  8  9  
Set[0][6] = 0  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  
Set[0][7] = 0  1  2  3  4  6  7  8  9  
Set[0][8] = 9  
Set[0][9] = 9  
Set[1][0] = 1  
Set[1][1] = 2  
Set[1][2] = 
Set[1][3] = 1  
Set[1][4] = 1  
Set[1][5] = 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  
Set[1][6] = 4  
Set[1][7] = 6  
Set[1][8] = 7  
Set[1][9] = 4  
9 positions: 0 0 
1 positions: 1 0 
0 positions: 0 1 
1 positions: 0 1 
3 positions: 0 1 
4 positions: 0 1 
6 positions: 0 1 
7 positions: 0 1 
8 positions: 0 1 
9 positions: 0 1 
2 positions: 1 1 
9 positions: 0 2 
9 positions: 0 3 
1 positions: 1 3 
0 positions: 0 4 
1 positions: 0 4 
2 positions: 0 4 
4 positions: 0 4 
5 positions: 0 4 
6 positions: 0 4 
7 positions: 0 4 
8 positions: 0 4 
9 positions: 0 4 
1 positions: 1 4 
0 positions: 0 5 
1 positions: 0 5 
2 positions: 0 5 
3 positions: 0 5 
4 positions: 0 5 
5 positions: 0 5 
7 positions: 0 5 
8 positions: 0 5 
9 positions: 0 5 
2 positions: 1 5 
3 positions: 1 5 
4 positions: 1 5 
5 positions: 1 5 
6 positions: 1 5 
7 positions: 1 5 
8 positions: 1 5 
0 positions: 0 6 
2 positions: 0 6 
3 positions: 0 6 
4 positions: 0 6 
5 positions: 0 6 
6 positions: 0 6 
7 positions: 0 6 
8 positions: 0 6 
9 positions: 0 6 
4 positions: 1 6 
0 positions: 0 7 
1 positions: 0 7 
2 positions: 0 7 
3 positions: 0 7 
4 positions: 0 7 
6 positions: 0 7 
7 positions: 0 7 
8 positions: 0 7 
9 positions: 0 7 
6 positions: 1 7 
9 positions: 0 8 
7 positions: 1 8 
9 positions: 0 9 
4 positions: 1 9
```